# Entity Framework Core adding to .Net Core Web Api - IRelationalTypeMappingSource problem

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have .Net Core web API works fine. When I try to add Entity Framework Core, firstly, compile-error. It said, I must add Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces even though I used .Net Core 3.1. When I added this, compiled well but when api run, it gives this exception. I cannot find any solution of this exception on internet:

When run .net core web api (debugging):

```
namespace CoreWebApi{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();           

        services.AddDbContext<PKDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LocalConnection")));


        services.AddScoped(typeof(IBankProduct), typeof(BankProductRepo));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IProductType), typeof(ProductTypeRepo));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IProductRequest), typeof(ProductRequestRepo));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IProfile), typeof(ProfileRepo));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(INotification), typeof(NotificationRepo));

    }

  
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }


        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
}
```

Startup codes works fine. When my dbContext class (PKDbContext) runs, it gives exception on this part: (**: base(options)**)

```
public class PKDbContext : DbContext{
    public PKDbContext() { }

    public PKDbContext(DbContextOptions<PKDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        // some codes
    }
}
```

Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code
The database provider attempted to register an implementation of the 'IRelationalTypeMappingSource' service. This is not a service defined by EF and as such must be registered as a provider-specific service using the 'TryAddProviderSpecificServices' method.

*Edit: I am using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

**Edit: I added csproj file code:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <StartupObject>CoreWebApi.Program</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0-preview.7.20365.15" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="5.0.0-preview.7.20365.15" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code

Comment: App can not run any code, it gives exception when starts at here:

        public myDbContext(DbContextOptions<myDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
         
        }

Comment: Edit the question with the code which you are trying to run, it's hard to provide any help without knowing where the issue lies.

Comment: Can you add the csproj?

Comment: I added .csproj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to change db to Sql Server. I've removed Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql and added Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer and problem's solved.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue, turns out the current version of Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql requires a version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore between 3.1.8 and before 5.0.0

Downgrading Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore to the version before 5.0.0 (3.1.11) solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

if you want `EF Core 5` to work with MySQL you need to install `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 5.0.0-alpha.2`

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="5.0.0-alpha.2" />
```

or you can downgrade `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` to a more stable version which is `3.2.4` along with `EF Core 3.1.12`

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.12" />
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.2.4" />
```

PS: for more information visit `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` [compatibility section](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql)